# Interface with different types

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

I have a problem where I have two implemention that I want to share a interface, but they will have different types for "the same parameter", see one `Guid` and one `Int`.

For example:

```
public Class1 : IGetObject {
   GetObjectBy(int Id);
}

public Class2 : IGetObject {
   GetObjectBy(Guid Id);
}
```

At the other end of the application the "Id" argument will come from a user input which is string. So I also have

```
public GetObjectMethod(){
  string id = dropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
  IGetObject GetObject = Shared.Instance.GetObject;
  var result = GetObject.GetObjectBy(id);
}
```

How can I make the implemention share the interface so I don't have to change something in the GetObjectMethod?

What I think is maybe an idea is to create a new **type** like this and declare that in the common interface. In that way the implemention know which propery it should use:

```
public class ObjectId(){
   public ObjectId(string id){
      if(Guid.TryParse(id)){
       /// Figure out what value that should be set
      }
   }

   public Guid ObjectIdAsGuid;
   public Int  ObjectIdAsInt;
}
```

What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: What's your interface definition? I guess it should have 2 overloads of `GetObjectBy`

Comment: then both must be implemented.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to declare the interface. Even if I had a overload  the GetObjecetMethod needs to determine which type it is on the "id" argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create GetObjectBy method which accepts string (or object), and then parse (or cast) id in implementation of interface:

```
public Class1 : IGetObject {
   public Foo GetObjectBy(string Id) 
   { 
      var id = Int32.Parse(Id); 
      //... 
   }
}

public Class2 : IGetObject {
   public Foo GetObjectBy(string Id) 
   {
       var id = new Guid(Id); 
       //... 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to share a interface, but they will have different types for "the same parameter"

One way to do that is to make the interface generic:

```
public interface IGetObject<T>
{
   void GetObjectBy(T Id);
}

public class Class1 : IGetObject<int> {
   void GetObjectBy(int Id);
}

public class Class2 : IGetObject<Guid> {
   void GetObjectBy(Guid Id);
}
```

Otherwise you'd need two overloads, but each class will have to implement both functions:

```
public interface IGetObject
{
   void GetObjectBy(int Id);
   void GetObjectBy(Guid Id);
}

public class Class1 : IGetObject {
   void GetObjectBy(int Id);
   void GetObjectBy(Guid Id);
}

public class Class2 : IGetObject<Guid> {
   void GetObjectBy(int Id);
   void GetObjectBy(Guid Id);
}
```

Comment: With this approch I need to implement a "guess type" function in the GetObjectMethod, and if I want to extend it later I need to change the method impemention.

Comment: Maybe you should include an example using [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) to let him work with `string` input like he needs to. I think that'd be my preferred solution.

Comment: @TimS.  How do you mean by Convert.ChangeType?

Comment: Something like `GetObjectBy((T)Convert.ChangeType(id, typeof(T)))`. But actually, I'm not so sure that will work, because you might not have that `T` available. Maybe a `string` or `object` parameter is the only good way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class for your ID, which combine both ID types to one more general ID

Comment: @SimonEdström:  I think this is basically your last suggestion, the ObjectID class, which I think is a good idea.  You've got the concept of an ID, and it should be treated as a class, that can, as necessary, be converted to ints, Guids, or anything else.